# how to stop posts from shrinking?

Tags: html, css

I made this blog but when I post on it the more the posts get when I scroll down the posts keep shrinking until they get completely out of shape specially when the screen is mobile sized how can I stop the posts from shrinking and fix this?

I do not know which part of the code is associated with this problem so I post my base.html and post.html please let me know if something else is needed

Thanks in advance

[image: this is how it looks like]

base.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>  {% block title %}{% endblock %}  </title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'website/favicon.ico' %}" />
</head>
  <body>
    {% include 'top-menu.html'%}
    <div class="container">
      {% if messages %}
       {% for message in messages %}
         <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
           <strong>{{ message }}</strong>
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      {% block content %}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

post.html

```html
<div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 25px"></div>
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header" id="linkilink">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{post.title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        {{ post.body|truncatewords_html:30 }}
        <hr>
        <p> <a href="{% url 'userinfo' %}"><img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" width="75" height="75"></a> <div style="color: rgb(133, 131, 131);"> Author: {{ post.author }} </div> </p>

       
        <a href="{% url 'detail' post.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-small" id="readbutton">Read More <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-three-dots" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M3 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3z"/>
          </svg></a>
          


        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
         {% if user == post.author%}
        
         <a href="{% url 'update' post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" >Update</a>


            <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" id="deleteButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"/>
                <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"/>
              </svg></a>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% if user == post.author%}
<div>
  <body>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <div class="icon-box">
          </div>                
          <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>    
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p  class="text-muted">Do you really want to delete {{ post.title }}? This process cannot be undone.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>     
  </body>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Python and Django - it is only problem with CSS, HTML and Bootstrap. So I remove tags.

Comment: well which tags??? cause I'm new to all this I'm actually clueless

Comment: I deleted tags `pythons` and `django`

Answer (score 0):

In your post.html, each post is wrapped in a Bootstrap card. To prevent shrinking, you can set a fixed height for the cards, so they maintain a consistent size. Add a CSS class to your cards and define a min-height for them.

```
<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow post-card">
    <!-- Card content here -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-card {
    min-height: 400px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
}
```

In your `post.html`, you are using the `truncatewords_html` filter to limit the number of words displayed. Be cautious with the number of words you truncate. If it's too small, it might affect the card height and cause shrinking. Adjust the word limit as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I edited the height and width but the posts all get pushed to the right side when I scroll down in mobile size and they still shrink I tried margin left and right too but that didn't work so why's that?